# Damage mitigation in God of War series

Tags: god-of-war, god-of-war-3

Suppose that I'm using a costume that reduces the damage dealt/received by some amount.

-Does it also affects my "circle combos",for example in GoW III at the final battle with Zeus one can throw him in the air,press circle and there is an usual animation where Kratos punches him twice and in GoW II one may press circle and use a soldier as projectiles in order to hit other stronger enemies. Does the costume affect the damage dealt in such ocasions?

-Is there any enemy with a move that has a fixed amount of damage,that is,no matter the costume,it will always take as much life?

I'm asking this after watching a battle against Zeus (Kratos wearing Apollo costume that reduces the damage dealt) where seemingly the player took the same amount of time of a regular Skin to defeat Zeus using the same strategy.